# Class Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-8

I've created my laravel project as follows:

```
laravel new my_app
```

This creates my project using laravel version 8. As I want to use Laravel 7, I modified composer.json:

```
 "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
```

After that I run:

```
composer update
```

which ends with the error described (Class Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter not found )

In fact, that class doesn't exist in Support facade. Shouldn't downgrade process correct this?

Comment: any particular reason you don't want to use Laravel 8? Laravel 7 will no longer be receiving bug fixes shortly (in 2 weeks)

Comment: I was asked to. Not my choice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is from code in your application; specifically your `App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider`. Everything that isn't in `vendor` is considered your application and is not touched by any upgrade or downgrade. The `laravel/laravel` package only sets up your application skeleton for you. You can install Laravel 7 specifically with `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel:^7.0 yourproject`; you can find the instructions in the install guide for Laravel 7.

Otherwise you will need to potentially copy the Service Providers from `laravel/laravel` version 7 into your application so you are not using providers from Laravel 8 as some things have changed and some new features were introduced. And there would be other changes as well.

[Laravel 7.x Docs - Installation - via Composer Create-Project](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/installation) `composer create-project`